# How to compare a custom data type in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a custom data type which I would like to compare.

```
data Tile = Wall | Ground | Storage | Box | Blank
```

I would like to do `instance-of-tile == Box`

I've tried using `==` like so

```
tileToInteger :: Tile -> Integer
tileToInteger tile 
  | tile == Blank || tile == Wall = 1
  | otherwise = 2
```

I've also tried

```
tileToInteger :: Eq => Tile -> Integer
```

The error message from `stack build` is

```
No instance for (Eq Tile) arising from a use of ‘==’
    • In the first argument of ‘(||)’, namely ‘tile == Blank’
      In the expression: tile == Blank || tile == Wall
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for an equation for ‘tileToInteger’: tile == Blank || tile == Wall
```

Here's the full sample code

```
data Tile = Wall | Ground | Storage | Box | Blank

getTileAtXY :: Integer -> Integer -> Tile
getTileAtXY x y
  | x == 0 && y == 0 = Box
  | otherwise = Ground

tileToInteger :: Tile -> Integer
tileToInteger tile 
  | tile == Blank || tile == Wall = 1
  | otherwise = 2

main :: IO ()
main = print (tileToInteger (getTileAtXY 1 0))
```

**Background**

- Exercise from [Penn Engineering university](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/fall16/hw/02-ho-datatypes.html) course
- Using stack version 1.9.3.1

Comment: Side note: Stack is just a build tool, so its version doesn't tell much about what your code is actually using. In future questions, you can instead tell us which resolver Stack is using to build your code, which allows us to find out the corresponding versions of GHC and Stackage libraries. The resolver is specified in the `stack.yaml` file you are using (and if you aren't sure about where it is, `stack path --config-location` will tell you).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error

> ```
> No instance for (Eq Tile) arising from a use of ‘==’
> ```

Says that you use `(==)` with two `Tile`s, but that the compiler did not found an instance of `Eq Tile` where you defined the `(==)` function for `Tile`s.

You can make it an instance of the [**`Eq`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq):

```
data Tile = Wall | Ground | Storage | Box | Blank deriving Eq
```

If you automatically derive `Eq`, then Haskell considers two objects of `Tile` equal given the data constructors (`Wall`, `Ground`, ...) are the same, and all their arguments are the same. Since the data constructors of your `Tile` data type have no arguments, this thus simply means that `Wall` is equal to `Wall`, `Ground` is equal to `Ground`, etc.

In your function `tileToInteger` however, you do not *need* to use `(==)` at all, you can use [*pattern matching* [Haskell-wiki]](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching), like:

```
tileToInteger :: Tile -> Integer
tileToInteger Blank = 1
tileToInteger Wall = 1
tileToInteger _ = 2
```

You can implement the `(==)` function for `Tile`s with pattern matching, like:

```
instance Eq Tile where
    Wall == Wall = True
    Ground == Ground = True
    Storage == Storage = True
    Box == Box = True
    Blank == Blank = True
    _ == _ = False
```

The above is however equivalent to what `deriving Eq` will do, so usually one only implements `Eq` manually if two `Tile`s are considered equivalent in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

You can *derive* the methods for comparison automatically:

```
data Tile = Wall | Ground | Storage | Box | Blank deriving (Eq)
```

And then you can use `==` and `/=` to compare `Tile`s for equality and inequality.